# I want to loop over an int comparing it with an int array java

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I want to compare an int x value with an int array data[i][j] using a do loop. data got the values 1236, 1238, 1240 and 1250. and x = 1237

my loop looks like this:

```
boolean go = true;

do {
    if (x == data[i][j]) {
        System.out.println("" + x)
        go = false;
    } else {
        x++
    }

} 
while (go)
```

Comment: What is your question? Why do you compare 'x' with 'go' as a loop condition?

Comment: `x` is int, `go` is boolean. Compiler error.

Comment: Do you understand that you will increment x until it get equal to `data[i][j]` and then print it. Isn't it easier just print `data[i][j]`?

Comment: The program i am working on chooses an ideal value and then compares it to the existing values stored in the array. I only want the value 1238 to be printed after the loop is done

Comment: @Jesper if so just add `System.out.println(1238)` and remove loop.

Comment: No because, this loop is just an smaler version of a bigger one where the value of x is calculated of diffrent values and then the loop chooses the closest existing value from the array.

Answer (score 0):

x is int, go is boolean. Compiler error.   Try this.

```
  do{
       if(x==data[i][j]){
       System.outln(""+x)
       go = false;
    }
    else{x++}
    }

    while(go == true);
```

Comment: go == true  !! just use go

Comment: it's for his understanding. It seems he is newbie in java.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the original asker actually wanted to do this:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++) {
        if(x == data[i][j]) {
            System.out.println("found " + x + " at " + i + " " + j);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As in finding the position of x in data.

Comment: Not really, but it is close to what i wanted. i want to compare the calculated value of 'x' to the existing values of the arrya and if they arent matching x will do x=x+1; and then it goes through the loop again and compares to the array until the values match. and then it shall break.